# How to not serialize calculated attr in JointJS model?

Tags: jointjs

I want to limit what data is serialized when I write a JointJS model to JSON. I have a number of display attrs that are 'calculated' values.

My Element mode looks like the following:

```
joint.shapes.model.Name = joint.dia.Element.extend({

        markup: '<g class="rotatable"><text class="name"/></g>',

        defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({

            type: 'model.Name',
            modelName: 'UNKNOWN',

            size: { width: 80, height: 80 },

            attrs: {

                '.name': {
                    'font-family': 'Arial', 'font-size': 13,
                }
            }
        }, joint.dia.Element.prototype.defaults),

        // Set the view properties based on the model properties
        modelToViewAttr: function() {

            // It is more complicated that this, but this is the basic idea
            this.attr({'.name' : { text: model.modelName }});

        }
    });
```

After I load the model, I call `modelToViewAttr` to initialize how the model is displayed (this is a little annoying, but it separates the model from the view).

When it is serialized, I get the following:

```
{
    "type": "model.Name",
    "modelName": "UNKNOWN",
    "size": {
        "width": 80,
        "height": 80
    },
    "position": {
        "x": 1000,
        "y": 100
    },
    "angle": 0,
    "id": "59c2cd68-eaa9-4bef-8232-fa74b58344ab",
    "z": 6,
    "attrs": {
        ".name": {
            "text": "modelName"
        },
    }
}
```

I want to get the following instead:

```
{
    "type": "model.Name",
    "modelName": "UNKNOWN",
    "size": {
        "width": 80,
        "height": 80
    },
    "position": {
        "x": 1000,
        "y": 100
    },
    "angle": 0,
    "id": "59c2cd68-eaa9-4bef-8232-fa74b58344ab",
    "z": 6,
}
```

Notice there is no `attrs` item because it is calculated by `modelToViewAttr`.